# What is the Windows equivalent of the Unix command cat? 

Tags: windows, unix, cat

I want to do exactly what unix "cat" does, but on my PC. Is there a simple equivalent command for the Windows command line?

Specifically I want to create a file from all the files of a given type in a folder

In Unix:

```
cat *fna >all_fna_files.fna
```

(which joins all the ".fna" text files into one big text file)

Comment: None of these suggestions can accept a redirect of STDIN.

Comment: Powershell: `cat file.txt`

Comment: Cross-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60244/11683

Comment: The answers provided are all commands available in different shells. Is there an executable which sends its arguments to stdout?

Comment: @phreed If you are working on cmd.exe, there is the `echo` built-in. For PowerShell there is the `Write-Output` cmdlet (which also happens to be aliased by `echo`).

Answer (score 495):

### **`type`**

It works across `command.com`, `cmd`, and PowerShell (though in the latter it's an alias for `Get-Content`, so is `cat`, so you could use either).
From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPE_(DOS_command)) (emphasis mine):

> In computing, type is a command in various VMS. AmigaDOS, CP/M, DOS, OS/2 and Microsoft Windows command line interpreters (shells) such as COMMAND.COM, cmd.exe, 4DOS/4NT and Windows PowerShell. It is used to display the contents of specified files. **It is analogous to the Unix cat command.**

```
C:\>echo hi > a.txt
C:\>echo bye > b.txt
C:\>type a.txt b.txt > c.txt
C:\>type c.txt
hi
bye
```

Comment: Good informative answer, so +1. Wish that I could give Microsoft a -1 though for the utterly ambiguous command name. `type filename` makes me think that the command should return the type of file, not the contents of the file!

Comment: Cat doesn't really seem much better.

Comment: @PenguinCoder Why are you blaming MS?  Seems to me they simply followed an existing convention from VMS.

Comment: @DavidBoike Although cat is from con_cat_enate AFAIR.

Comment: If I could go back in time I'd suggest "dump".

Comment: @davidboike It is much better because it actually means and stands for what it does: *The cat program is a standard Unix utility that concatenates and lists files. The name is an abbreviation of catenate, a synonym of concatenate.* [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) Can you say the same for the MS-DOS `type` command??

Comment: @PenguinCoder Except `type` doesn't concatenate files; it just `type`s their contents to the screen.  Its the piping in the example that is actually combining the files, not the `type` command.

Comment: @Andy Will not argue further, however quoting the exact answer: *From the Wikipedia article (emphasis mine): [sic] It is used to display the contents of specified files. **It is analogous to the Unix cat command**.*

Comment: @PenguinCoder a·nal·o·gous/əˈnaləgəs/ 
Adjective: 1.Comparable in **certain respects**, typically in a way that makes clearer the nature of the things compared.

Comment: MS-DOS likely inherited `TYPE` from CP/M by way of QDOS. [The TYPE command displays the content of the ASCII source file ufn on the currently logged disk at the console device.](http://web.archive.org/web/20100812024127/http://www.iso.port.ac.uk/~mike/interests/chistory/documents/cpm-22-manual/ch1.html#Section_1.4.5)

Comment: @Andy  are you sure it doesn't concatenate? C:\>type a.txt b.txt > c.txt  See, the two parameters to the TYPE command there and it's > not >>. Typing each is concatenating them. Also it looks like maybe redirection operators like > and >> are not actually called pipes. Pipes are just one form of redirection, you know, | , and not used here. See  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Piping

Comment: @barlop no, typing each will display each file one after the other, to stdout, and the > redirects stdout to a file.  I misspoke when I said piping, it is redirecting.  Take out the > c.txt and a.txt and b.txt will remain unchanged, so its not doing the cat, its taking advantage of the fact it will output multiple files and clever use of redirection.

Comment: @Andy isn't $cat a.txt b.txt   also outputting a.txt then b.txt to stdout? a.txt and b.txt remain unchanged. just like with type. What's the difference in result between cat a.txt b.txt >c  and type a.txt b.txt >c ?   or,  cat a.txt b.txt  and type a.txt b.txt ? you can replace the word cat with the word type, and it seems to have the same effect. So I don't see how you can say that cat concatenates and type doesn't.

Comment: @Andy I think the core point that was missed in this comment chain was the perspective that `type` and `cat` both _do_ catenate the files: they're just writing the result to the one spot that's the most sensible: stdout. Frankly, I think they're both bad for intuitive uptake/guessing/recognition, and both about equally sensible once you think up of a way to remember them (`type` "types" file contents out to the output, `cat` (con)catenates files to the output).

Comment: Make sure you set the output file to some other directory, specially if you're using wildcards to append files. Eg " type *.sql > all.sql". Otherwise you'll end up duplicated content. Yes the command type is that stupid.

Comment: type won't read from stdin

Answer (score 33):

From the command shell:

```
copy a.txt + b.txt + c.txt output.txt
```

(But that follows the command shells use of control-Z as an end of file marker, so not suitable in some cases).

In PowerShell:

```
get-content a.txt,b.txt,c.txt | out-file output.txt
```

and you can control (using `-Encoding` parameter) the file encoding (which allows transcoding by using different encoding for the read and write).

Comment: PowerShell aliases `cat` to `Get-Content` too. It's designed to accept many basic Linux commands without much, if any, modification.

Comment: Bob, except if switches and options are involved.

Comment: @Richard: Copy /b a + b + c output.txt doesn't check for on Ctrl-Z.  Both variants will copy the entire file if there is NO ctrl-Z in the file.

Comment: Note that you can include wildcards too, the way wildcards work in windows means you won't be messed up by the expansion list not containing a `+`, so `copy [/b] *.fna all_fna_files.fna`..

Comment: if I recall from an old test I once did, using COPY with /B  to concatenate, will ignore CTRL-Z/EOF markers, and will do the concatenation properly!  but judging by copy /? you may need to do a lot of /B like it seems maybe after copy, after each src file and after the dest file.. strange.

Comment: You can also use `type` command like `type *.txt > file.merge`

Answer (score 5):

I have just used the cat command in DOS (Windows 7 Pro) in the following manner and successfully merged 3 files (log1.txt, log2.txt, log3.txt) into a single file:

```
cat log*.txt >> myBigLogFile.txt
```

Note: `cat log*.txt > myBigLogFile2.txt` also provide the same result, but it'll override the previous file.

Comment: maybe you have GNU for Windows, or Cygwin in your path, or are using powershell because cat does not exist on a clean Windows 7 system. DOS is no longer a thing, but most people would use it to refer to cmd.exe.

Comment: [Windows CMD and MS-DOS are not the same thing](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There's no `cat` command in both cmd and DOS, only `cat` alias in powershell

Comment: you can also use `type` command `type *.txt > file.merge`