# FFMPEG: Windows binaries with globbing (libavformat) support?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am struggling to get `ffmpeg` to combine a bunch of images in to a video which have a format with a full 17 digit timestamp.  17 digits is well beyond what -i `%d` will support.  So I want to use globbing to simply order them using full filename, however I keep getting the error:

```
[image2 @ 0000000002d0d1e0] Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not supported by this libavformat build
```

Does anyone know where I can get pre-built binaries to get around this problem?  Here are example filenames I have:

```
screenshot_20150417165520593.png
screenshot_20150417165520805.png
screenshot_20150417165521005.png
```

Comment: Guessing you're using windows? It seems Windows builds don't support globbing/true-wildcards so it's suggested to rename your input/source files :(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201164/ffmpeg-error-pattern-type-glob-was-selected-but-globbing-is-not-support-ed-by
https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f

Comment: This might be an old version of `libavformat`. You should upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Not a windows user, but ffmpeg supports reading data from an input stream.

In Linux, you can do something like: cat *.png | ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i - test.mp4

Looks like Powershell might let you do this.

From an answer at [What is the Windows equivalent of the Unix command cat?](https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat) , you might be able to use:

get-content *.png | ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i -

Comment: I just tried "get-content", and it seems it first reads all the data into RAM, so not very suitable for hundreds of images.