# Configure Command Line or Powershell to alias the Unix `cat` command to `type`?

Tags: unix, powershell

The new codebase I am working with uses the UNIX `cat` in unit testing (in a `package.json` file: `"upload-coverage": "yarn run test --watchAll=false && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | codacy-coverage",`).

Alas, I am on windows and `cat` throws an error. I've found this info: [What is the Windows equivalent of the Unix command cat?](https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat?newreg=4beaf929891a4dbe94ca5989b8f6ecc7)

... however, I don't have the liberty to modify `package.json`. Is it possible to configure the command line (or powershell) to do the `type` command when it encounters `cat`?

I have thus far only used the Commandline... don't think that's possible there. Powershell is totally new to me.

Thanks for any help you can offer here!

Comment: `doskey cat=type`. [Doskey - recall commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html)

Comment: Create a `cat.bat` file, or use `Set-Alias` in powershell.

Comment: @dirkt where do I put that `cat.bat`? What do I write in it?

Comment: @DavidPostill, typing that (with either the cmd window OR powershell), followed by running the test, nonetheless produces the same error: "'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 255."  ... is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `.bat` file in any directory in your path. Check your path with

```
echo %PATH%
```

and see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) how to extend the default path.

For `cat.bat`, use something along the lines of

```
@echo off
type %1
```

I tested that this works from the commandline. I didn't write a `package.json` file and test it with node, so if your version of node does something funny when executing scripts, it still might not work.

Powershell actually already aliases `cat` to `Get-Content` (you can verify this with `Get-Alias`), so if it doesn't already work, adding an alias won't help.